# copy constructor doesn't work when the class is used as a map value

Tags: c++

I can't find a simpler way to explain my problem than straight pasting it here(a simplified version though).
I have a templated class with necessary assignment operator, default constructor and a `common` copy constructor. when I try to use this class in my code I get an error as follows:

```
#include<map>
#include<vector>

template<class T>
class BufferContainer
{
public:

    BufferContainer& operator=(BufferContainer& other)
    {
        buffer = other.get();
        return *this;
    }

    BufferContainer( const BufferContainer& other ) :
        buffer( other.get() )
     {
     }

    BufferContainer(){
    }

    std::vector<T>& get() {
            return buffer;
    }

    void add(T value) {

        buffer.push_back(value);
    }

    std::vector<T> buffer;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, BufferContainer<int> > myMap;
    myMap[1].add(1);
    return 1;
}
```

and the error is:

```
Practice $ g++ template.cpp 
template.cpp: In instantiation of ‘BufferContainer<T>::BufferContainer(const BufferContainer<T>&) [with T = int; BufferContainer<T> = BufferContainer<int>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:105:31:   required from ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = BufferContainer<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:458:11:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = BufferContainer<int>; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, BufferContainer<int> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = BufferContainer<int>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’
template.cpp:38:9:   required from here
template.cpp:16:26: error: passing ‘const BufferContainer<int>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::vector<T>& BufferContainer<T>::get() [with T = int]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I will appreciate if you help me with the methods to solve this issue and, more importantly, tell me why i got this error.
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `get()` function is not `const`-qualified, and you are invoking it through a reference to `const` in your copy-constructor:

```
BufferContainer( const BufferContainer& other ) :
//               ^^^^^
    buffer( other.get() )
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
}
```

This is why the compiler is complaining. You cannot call a non-`const` function through a reference to `const`. Having a reference to `const` means you're not going to modify the state of the referenced object, so you can only invoke functions that promise not to modify the object's state. That's what the `const` qualifier on member functions is for - to make that promise.

Therefore, your member function `get()` should be qualified as `const`, and return a reference to a `const` vector:

```
std::vector<T> const& get() const 
//             ^^^^^        ^^^^^
{
    return buffer;
}
```

If you need your non-`const` function `get()` because you want to allow clients to modify the internal `buffer` (advice: consider whether this is really a good idea), then you will have to provide *two* overloads of `get()`:

- A `const`-qualified one that returns a reference to a `const` vector (like the one shown above)
- A non-`const`-qualified one that returns a reference to a modifiable vector (like the original `get()`)

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that you should provide a `const` version of your `get()` method:

```
const std::vector<T>& get() const 
{
    return buffer;
}
```

since the copy constructor rightly takes a `const` reference:

```
BufferContainer( const BufferContainer& other )
```

This means you can only call `const` methods on `other`.

Note that the return type is of the `const` version of `get()` is a `const` reference. This is required for const correctness.

Comment: juanchopanza, thanks. but this means I will not be able to modify the result of .get() anymore. is that true?

Comment: @rahman: You can (and should) provide two versions of `get()`, one const (like juanchopanza's) and the other one non-const (like yours).

Comment: @rahman I edited my question to make it clear that you can have two versions, a `const` and a non `const` one.

Comment: Thank you all. All questions were good. don't know which one to mark as true.

Answer (score 1):

`other` is taken as `const` reference and `get` is a non-const method. You can't call a non-const method from a const reference.